# How to subscribe by email to a Google Groups mailing list with daily-digest option?

Tags: google-groups, mailing-list

I'm setting up a Google Group for use as a mailing list with a non-technical audience. I want to be able to allow them to perform all necessary actions without using anything but their email address.

I see that it is possible to subscribe or unsubscribe by sending an email to

```
mygroup+unsubscribe@googlegroups.com
```

or

```
mygroup+subscribe@googlegroups.com
```

Is there a similar email target that would let me perform the following actions:

1. Change a subscription from regular delivery to daily-digest
2. Subscribe with daily-digest turned on from the start

Comment: Tumbleweed! Ironically, I forgot that I asked this. But I still would like an answer . . .

Comment: Gosh, I wish someone would answer this question!

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do that by email, but changing the group's email settings can all be done fairly easily. When you go to Groups Home, you'll see the list of groups that you're a member of. If you have admin access you'll be able to edit the settings for that group.

As for the users on your list, they'll be able to edit their individual preferences as well: https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1047839?hl=en&ref_topic=2459492